# Al referirse a "camiones", ¿hay alguna palabra que se use con más frecuencia que "camión"?

Tags: méxico

¿En Mexico especialmente (no España) al referirse a camiones, hay alguna palabra que se use con más frecuencia que "camión"?

---

In Mexico especially, when referring to trucks, is there a word which is used with more frequency than "camión"?

Comment: I don't get it in English. That makes no sense. Small trucks like SUV ones are called trocas.

Answer (score 1):

Realmente no existe una palabra que sustituya a "**camión**" para referirse al mismo como vehículo de transporte, sin embargo en México normalmente se utiliza la palabra "**camión**" para referirse a los autobuses que van de un lugar a otro dentro de la misma provincia y "**autobús**" los que van de una provincia a otra. A los vehículos del transporte escolar y personal de oficinas, también se les conoce como "la ruta" o "camiones".

Por otra parte un "**camión de redilas**" o de tablas alrededor, pueden llevar carga o transportar personas.

Actualmente a parte de "camiones" (autobuses que van dentro de la misma localidad o provincia), también se dice metrobús, minibús, orugas, peseros (porque antes costaban un peso D.F.),... aunque todos son autobuses pero de distinto tipo.

A parte de esto, "**los camiones**" en México siguen siendo los trailers, los cerrados, los de jaula, lo que llevan lona...

Comment: troca
s f (N) Camión de carga: “Ahora que entraron trocas y que habrá madera y negocio, la tajada es para todos” https://dem.colmex.mx/Ver/troca

Comment: Bueno, en el norte del país, sobre todo en tijuana, a los autobuses de transporte urbano, de mediano aforo, (o Microbuses) se les llama *Calafias* . jocosamente si dices que "Estás esperando la *burra*" se sobreentiende que en poco tiempo serás pasajero, no del cuadrúpedo ungulado sino de un vehiculo como los mencionados.